# Disconnected from Twitter Streaming api, "admin logout"

Tags: twitter

I've recently started using the streaming API and was connecting with Basic auth to test it out but it's now stopped streaming. I get the error:

```
{
    "disconnect":{
        "code":7,
        "stream_name":"XXXX-userstreamxxxx",
        "reason":"admin logout"
    }
}
```

The only answer I can find is, "You've connected again with the same credentials and the oldest connection was disconnected", but I don't know how I would fix that and I can't find any discreet answers via google. My assumption is that I SHOULD use the same login/password combo because that only makes sense, but I don't know what else can be changed.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're only allowed to have one stream open at a time per account.  So if you have one open, and you try to open another one with the same username/password, this will happen.